# Evaluate the expression $\sqrt{6-2\sqrt5} + \sqrt{6+2\sqrt5}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, nested-radicals

$$\sqrt{6-2\sqrt5} + \sqrt{6+2\sqrt5}$$

Can anyone tell me the formula to this expression.

I tried to solve in by adding the two expression together and get $\sqrt{12}$ but as I insert each expression separately in calculator the answer is above $\sqrt{12}$.

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{a-b}\neq\sqrt{2a},$ which is where I think you made your mistake.

Comment: Observe that the minimal polynomial for roots $6±2\sqrt5$ is $x^2-12x+16$

Comment: Consider $\sqrt{6.5 - 2.5} + \sqrt{6.5 + 2.5}$. The answer is not $\sqrt{13}$.

Answer (score 10):

Set 
$$t=\sqrt{6-2\sqrt5} + \sqrt{6+2\sqrt5}$$
$$t^2=6-2\sqrt5+2\sqrt{(6-2\sqrt5)(6+2\sqrt5)}+6+2\sqrt5$$
$$t^2=12+2\sqrt{36-20}=12+2(4)=20$$
$$t^2=20\implies t=2\sqrt5$$

Answer (score 8):

**Hint**. Observe that
$$
(\sqrt{5}-1)^2=6-2\sqrt{5},\quad (\sqrt{5}+1)^2=6+2\sqrt{5}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $(\sqrt{5}\pm 1)^2 = 6 \pm 2 \sqrt{5}$.

Answer (score 1):

More generally,
if
$t 
=\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}+\sqrt{a-\sqrt{b}}
$,

$\begin{array}\\
t^2
&=(\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}+\sqrt{a-\sqrt{b}})^2\\
&=a+\sqrt{b}+2(\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}\sqrt{a-\sqrt{b}})+a-\sqrt{b}\\
&=2a+2\sqrt{(a+\sqrt{b})(a-\sqrt{b})}\\
&=2a+2\sqrt{a^2-b}\\
\text{so}\\
t
&=\sqrt{2a+2\sqrt{a^2-b}}\\
\end{array}
$

In this case,
$a=6$
and
$b=20$
so
$t
=\sqrt{2\cdot 6+2\sqrt{36-20}}
=\sqrt{12+8}
=\sqrt{20}
=2\sqrt{5}
$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\,\ \sqrt a + \sqrt b\, = \sqrt{(\sqrt a + \sqrt b)^2} = \sqrt{a+b +2{\sqrt{ab}}}.\ $ Here $\ a+b=12,\ \color{}{\sqrt{ab}} = 4.$

Comment: Did you mean $\sqrt{a + b + 2\sqrt{ab}}$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha = \sqrt{6+2\sqrt{5}}+\sqrt{6-2\sqrt{5}}$. Then
$$ \alpha^2 = 12+2\sqrt{36-20} = 20 $$
hence $\color{red}{\alpha=2\sqrt{5}}$.